# memory leaks OpenGL render

Tags: c++, opengl, memory-leaks, point-clouds

I am developing an application that use OpenGL to render a point cloud.
The number of points change at each iterations.
Here is the code that I use :

```
        glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
        glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

        glColorPointer(3, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0, cloud->colors.data());
        glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT,    0, p_cloud->vertices.data());
        glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, p_cloud->vertices.size());

        glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
```

The thing is that I get a memory leak only if I use it like this. If I comment the previous section it works well (but without display of course).

Is there a function to call after that?

Another question: is there a simple way to display it as a mesh?
I know the index of the triangles.

Comment: One question per question, please. Preferably one that makes sense.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Perfectly fine question.

Comment: To make sure that you diagnosed the problem properly: If you run this code for an extended period of time, does the amount of memory increase continually? More or less linearly with time? Or does the memory use just increase somewhat the first few times you execute this code, and then plateau?

Comment: @RetoKoradi : Yes the amount of memory increase linearly with the time till the end

Comment: If it does not happen without these lines of code, that looks like a memory leak in the driver then. Do you have a different machine (ideally with a GPU from a different vendor) you can try it on?

Answer (score 2):

The code fragment you posted one would naively assume that the only memory involved is that of the arrays/vectors within `p_cloud`.

However modern OpenGL implementations operate asynchronously. OTOH you get the guarantee that after `glDraw…` returns the memory pointed to is safe to deallocate. Which means that the OpenGL implementation has to create a shadow copy (and since GPU memory is not "persistent" this happens in your process' address space for convenience of the driver).

Usually this shadow copy get garbage collected eventually, but if your program terminates before that happens you're going to see a memory leak. Normally all shadow copies should be deallocated when the last OpenGL context that interact with it got destroyed.

Try out what happens if you properly tear down the OpenGL context before terminating the process. (If you're using GLUT, GLFW or similar this may require hacking into the source code of those).

Comment: Indeed the only memory involved is in p_cloud. For the moment I slow down the rendering function till I get a proper solution. I'll try figure out what happened later and let you know. Thx